# MVC - Need to pass data from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, uiviewcontroller

I need to pass some information I have in a view to the controller.
When it goes to the controller, I like to then send out an email with that information.
I was thinking about using the @HTML.ActionLink the view but from my understanding, that goes to an ActionResult which I do not want as I want to be able to send out an email and not go back to the View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with the post being done through jquery. There are other options but this was fresh in my mind since I just did it the other day.

HTML and javascript

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <input type="submit" value="SendEmail" onclick="SendEmail(); return false;" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SendEmail() {
        $.post('PathToController/SendEmail',
          {
              parameter: parameterValue
    })
        .success(function (result) {
           // Display a message that the email was sent????
        });
    }
</script>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("SendEmail")]
public string SendEmail(parameters)
{
}
```

You could also let the page handle the post as normal and not use the jquery. If this is the case, then your parameters would need to match the IDs of your controls you would need to use.